# React functional component state variable's setFunction is not working when it is called through another function reference

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have found this error while trying to build another React app. So I am only asking the main issue here in a demo app, I might not be able to change any rendering methods here since it is not the actual project.

Issue in simplified form -> I was building a app where two `count` will be shown and a `+ button` will be there next to that count value. When the button is clicked the count should be increased by 1. Unfortunately when I try to click on the button the value is increasing only the first time. After that the value is not even changing. But when I am implementing the same using Class component its working as expected.

**Functional Component**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Page(props) {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const [content, setContent] = useState({
        button: (value) => {
            return <button onClick={() => handlePlus(value)}>+</button>;
        },
    });

    function handlePlus(value) {
        console.log("value=", value);
        const data = count + 1;
        setCount((count) => data);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>Functional Component Count = {count}</span>
            {content.button(10)} // 10 will be replaced with another variable
        </div>
    );
}

export default Page;
```

**Class Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class PageClass extends Component {
    state = {
        count: 0,
        content: {
            button: (value) => {
                return (
                    <button onClick={() => this.handlePlus(value)}>+</button>
                );
            },
        },
    };

    handlePlus = (value) => {
        console.log("value=", value);
        this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>Class Component Count = {this.state.count}</span>
                {this.state.content.button(10)} // 10 will be replaced with another variable
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PageClass;
```

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Page from "./components/Page";
import PageClass from "./components/PageClass";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Page />
            <PageClass />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

However, If I replace that `content` state variable with normal `const` variable type and it is working as expected.

**Below is working when I am not using any hooks to render the button.**
But this is not helpful for my case.

```
    const content = {
        content: () => {
            console.log(count);
            return <button onClick={() => handlePlus(value)}>+</button>;
        },
    };
```

I was trying to create some re-usable components and hence I wanted to have that function in state variable which return button tag, so that I can implements some other logic there.

Comment: Why is `content` state at all?

Comment: Why would you save the button in the hook? You could just loop over `count` to render x buttons.

Comment: Actually this is not the main project. I was trying to render a delete button for a table. Where I am passing id of each variable to that function. And I wanted to make that table component re usabale. So I wanted to have something like this.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit since the question does not need to contain the answer when one is already accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` will be missing since you're passing a hard-coded `10`.

I'd recommend simplifying the `handlePlus` to just:

```
setCount(c => c + 1);
```

Then set the `onclick` like so:

```
<button onClick={handlePlus}>+</button>
```

And your code will work as expected as you can see in this snippet:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    const [content, setContent] = useState({
        content: (value) => {
            return <button onClick={handlePlus}>+</button>;
        },
    });
    
    function handlePlus(value) {
        setCount(c => c + 1);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{count}</span>
            {content.content(10)}
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

That said, I'd recommend removing the button from the hook, and just render it yourself:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Example = () => {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
    function handlePlus(value) {
        setCount(c => c + 1);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <span>{count}</span>
            <button onClick={handlePlus}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

See [React documentation](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState#setstate) about the `c => c + 1` syntax

Comment: This looks like working code. However I want to try implementating the same in my Main project. Will confirm the answer after tested there.

Comment: `setCount(c => c + 1);` didn't know something like that (arrow inside set) existed. Is there any reference that you can share for this? I wasn't able to find any.

Comment: I;ve added a link to the React docs where they explain this.

Comment: I have tested this and it was working for the last issue that I have posted. But, I this solution is not helpful for my case. I need to have the button returned from function from the state variable. I have added few more details above. I would really appreciate if you can check that once again.

Comment: I have tried some changes and your ans was working, Thank you so much. just have to change the 1 line function to mutli lines and it was working fine, 1 liner also works, but I am having few other logics which need mutli lines.